# Is it possible to upgrade the django version used by wirecloud?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Current version used in Wirecloud is 1.6, which in the django site is indicated as [insecure and not further maintained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/). The wirecloud codebase seems quite segregated, are there significant obstacles to upgrade to 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

> **Update**: WireCloud 0.9.0 will add support for Django 1.7-1.9 as we closed the related [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/83) :).

No, there are not significant obstacles to add support for Django 1.7+. Mainly, we need to add support for [Django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) as we currently use [south](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but this can be accomplished without any problem.

I have created a [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/83) regarding this issue in the WireCloud's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, this will help those using both Wirecloud and Django

Comment: Ticket closed :). The develop branch now supports Django 1.7-1.9. We are planning to release version 0.9.0 in February ;-), so stay tuned.